# Php fwrite and directories explained

Tags: php

I am having a lot of trouble with this. I am trying to create a text file in another `directory`  from the directory of the `php` file. I have being doing some research on how to do this and you have to do somethink like: `./error/my_error`.However this does not work with me. Any suggestions?

Here is what i have got so far:

```
$errorfile="my_error";
$fileopener=fopen($errorfile,"a+") or exit("Unable to open file!");
$errormessage = date('d/m/y h:i a', time()).": ".$today_date.": ".$mystufferrors."\n";
fwrite($fileopener,$errormessage);
```

Comment: What're you going to do with this file later on? Can it be created as temporary one?

Comment: no it needs to be "there" if you know what i mean.

Comment: Define "does not work for me". What does or doesn't it do?

Comment: it prints errormy_error.txt into the directory of my php file.this is not what i want

Comment: use `__DIR__` constant (it points to directory of php file) and `../` to go up or `/subdir` to go inside subduirectory. Example: `$errorfile = __DIR__ . '/error/my_error'`

Comment: no that did not work thanks anyway

Comment: if you got a file named "errormyerror", it means the "/" has been dropped. BTW I cannot see, where you append the "error" stuff in the code you provided.

Comment: All i thought a+ does is to add something at the end of my file and it preserves the file if it is there!